# Google Visualization: Sankey chart move label

Tags: charts, position, google-visualization, label

if the first line is to small, then the label will be cut (see pic). Does anyone knows a solution?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MRTIL.png)

Comment: please provide a sample of the data and any specific chart options, this will help reproduce the error, in order to find a solution...

Answer (score 1):

i found a solution:
set a top and buttom padding of the container

```
.sankeyChart {
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}
```

after every draw set the overflow to visible

```
container.find('svg').css("overflow", "visible");
```